# How do I make Web API generated workflows in Power Automate default to "turned on"?

Tags: workflow, power-automate, webapi, dataverse

I'm using the Dataverse Web API to create cloud workflows, which I can do successfully -- the only problem I'm having is the flow defaults to "turned off". Which property do I set in the workflow entity (or maybe clientdata json string?) to have the flow default to "turned on?"

Any clues?

I've messed with the statecode, statuscode, and componentstatus properties to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.

The rule is, per the documentation, that any workflow created (by a POST command) via the Dataverse WebAPI will always default to "statecode" of 0 ("Draft"). You must then issue a "PATCH" rest call and update the workflow, and set "statecode" to value of 1 ("Active"). The workflow's "workflowid" must be added to the end of the endpoint in parentheses.

```
PATCH -> https://{{webapiurl}}workflows(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx)

Body:
{
  "statecode": 1
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/update-delete-entities-using-web-api#basic-update